# save to localstorage with html jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, function, local-storage

Hello I have a big problem that I have tried to solve, but it just does not work. When you click on a card (`.card-1`), I want the card to `fadeOut` and that it would be saved in `localStorage`.

The function works but it is not saved in `localStorage`, what am I doing wrong, I have tried many different things?

It seems that `getItem` works because the function runs but when I refresh the app the card is still there. I use a section with class card-1 not a input

```
<section class="card-1"></section>
```

I am grateful for your help

```js
$(".card-1").click(function() {
  var storage = $(".card-1").val;
  if (localStorage.getItem("local", storage)) {
    $('.card-1').fadeOut();

    localStorage.setItem("local", storage);
  }
});
```

Comment: The developer tools have a tab (*Storage* for FF, and *Application -> Storage* for Chrome) which shows you what's in local storage. Can you verify that your data is actually getting saved there correctly?

Comment: You're using `getItem()` wrong.  It returns the value.  `if (localStorage.getItem("local") == whatever etc..`

Comment: Read the docs of  [`getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

Comment: That's not so much a question title as a series of tags... Please read [ask], especially the part about writing good titles.

Comment: Everyone assumes you are trying to store the value of inputs, but can you clarify this for us. What exactly are you trying to store? Are you familiar with how localStorage works (particularly regarding serialization and how data is written/overwritten)? What and how much data are you expecting to be able to retrieve? Tell us more about your end-goal here.

Comment: The card I want to fadeOut looks like this
<section class = "card-1"> </ section> 
I have tried to understand localstorage for a long while but it does not work for me and therefore I asked here because I do not know how to proceed when I tested so much. My main goal is that the card is gonna be fadeOut even after you refresh the page. It's seems to be impossible for me to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

### Demo 1

> *"My main goal is that the card is gonna be fadeOut even after you refresh the page. It's seems to be impossible for me to get this to work."*

That wasn't apparent in the question, but now that is cleared up, first I should inform you about `localStorage` as it pertains to your situation:

- `localStorage` stores data as Strings indefinitely (until a user uses `clear()` to completely clean it out, or `removeItem()` method, or by overwriting an existing key by using `setItem()` and a new value, or the 2 to 10MB limit was exceeded).
- `localStorage` storage limit is per domain. For example, site-x.com has 2MB of data with 8MB remaining and site-z.net has 4MB of stored data and 6MB left. Moreover, what is stored for one domain is not shared with any other domain.
- As a beneficial "side effect", data in `localStorage` is shared between all pages of a domain.

BTW there are 2 things that need to be pointed out concerning the ***OP*** (***O***riginal **P**ost):

```
var storage = $(".card-1").val;
```

Syntactically, it is wrong, it should be the following (assuming `.card-1` was a form control like an `<input>` or `<textarea>`):

`var storage = $(".card-1").val`**()**

Secondly, `<section>` is a block element not a form control so `val()` method and `.value` property will never work. The easiest way to know if an element is a form control is that it can have a `value` attribute.

This demo cannot run on this site because localStorage is blocked. See this **[PLUNKER 1](https://embed.plnkr.co/U9hpbYq3NxnBHy3uuPrT/)** and **[PLUNKER 2](https://embed.plnkr.co/kpnSYsfjh1SNvzRk8mOf/)**

#### Demo 1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 400 16px/1.5 Verdana;
    }
    
    [type=checkbox] {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #chx0:checked~.card-0 {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #chx1:checked~.card-1 {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #chx2:checked~.card-2 {
      display: none;
    }
    
    label,
    input {
      font-family: Consolas;
      font-variant: small-caps;
      font-size: 20px;
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    label {
      min-height: 30px;
      background: rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.4);
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 8px;
    }
    
    code {
      font-family: Courier New;
      background: rgba(121, 45, 121, 0.2);
    }
    
    kbd {
      border: 2px outset grey;
      border-radius: 8px;
      padding: 2px 4px;
      font-family: Verdana;
    }
    
    footer {
      height: 90px;
    }
    
    summary h3 {
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 10px auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <details>
    <summary>
      <h3>CSS</h3>
    </summary>
    <ul>
      <li>Click one of the <code>&lt;fieldset&gt;s</code> and it disappears because...
        <ul>
          <li>
            there's a nested <code>&lt;label&gt; [for="ID-of-Input"]</code> linked to an...
          </li>
          <li>
            invisible <code>&lt;input id="ID-of-Input"&gt; [type=checkbox]</code>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        A click on a <code>&lt;label&gt;</code> will be a click on its linked input
      </li>
      <li>
        By using the pseudo-class selector <code>:checked</code> and the general sibling combinator <code>~</code> the "younger" siblings are now subject to a switch that can manipulate CSS dramatically around them and on them. In the demo, each invisible
        checkbox will hide a specific <code>.card</code>.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>
      <h3>jQuery</h3>
    </summary>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Basically CSS is used to remove the targets and jQuery is used tp keep the current state of certain elements persistant.
      </li>
      <li>
        In the demo an <code>each()</code> will loop through the checkbox <code>#id</code>s and pass them through <code>getData()</code> function as keys. If any values of '1' are found, the checkbox <code>#id</code> that corresponds with the key gets
        checked.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </details>
  <h3>Instructions</h3>
  <p><kbd>Reload</kbd> this page and the cards that are gone continue to be so. In order to remove the data from <code>localStorage</code>, click the <kbd>Clear</kbd> button.</p>
  <hr>

  <input id='chx0' class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <input id='chx1' class='chx' type='checkbox'>
  <input id='chx2' class='chx' type='checkbox'>

  <fieldset class='card-0 card' data-id='chx0'>
    <label for='chx0'>Card 0</label>
  </fieldset>
  <hr>
  <fieldset class='card-1 card' data-id='chx1'>
    <label for='chx1'>Card 1</label>
  </fieldset>
  <hr>
  <fieldset class='card-2 card' data-id='chx2'>
    <label for='chx2'>Card 2</label>
  </fieldset>

  <input class='reload' type='button' value='Reload' style='float:left; margin:5px 10px 20px 0; width:20ch;background:cyan;color:#000'>
  <input class='clear' type='button' value='Clear' style='float:right; margin:5px 10px 20px 0; width:20ch;background:tomato;color:#fff'>

  <footer>&nbsp;</footer>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var data;

    $('.chx').each(function(i, c) {
      var key = this.id;
      data = getData(key);
      console.log(data);
      if (data === '1') {
        this.checked = true;
      }
    });

    $(".chx").on('click', function() {
      var key = this.id;
      var val = this.checked ? '1' : '0';
      setData(key, val);
    });

    function getData(key) {
      data = localStorage.getItem(key);
      if (data === null) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return data;
      }
    }

    function setData(key, value) {

      if (key === undefined || value === undefined) {
        return false;
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        return true;
      }
    }

    $('.reload').on('click', function() {
      location.reload(true);
    });

    $('.clear').on('click', function() {
      localStorage.clear();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

### Demo 2

You have a syntax error `$(".card-1").val;` should be `$(".card-1").val()`. Besides that, I haven't bothered to debug the rest. Don't use the click event on what I can only assume to be an `<input>` (it would be inconvenient to test a button's value), use either the change or input event (I recommend change if dealing with `localStorage`). The following demo features a simple use of `localStorage`.

This demo cannot run on this site because `localStorage` is blocked. See this **[PLUNKER 1](https://embed.plnkr.co/U9hpbYq3NxnBHy3uuPrT/)** and **[PLUNKER 2](https://embed.plnkr.co/kpnSYsfjh1SNvzRk8mOf/)**

#### Demo 2

```js
var data = getData('card-1');

console.log(data);

if (data) {
  $('.card-1').val(data);
}

$(".card-1").on('change', function() {
  var storage = $(this).val();
  setData.call(this, 'card-1', storage);
  $(this).fadeOut();
});

function getData(key) {
  var data = localStorage.getItem(key);
  if (data === null) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return data;
  }
}

function setData(key, value) {
  if (key === undefined || value === undefined) {
    return false;
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    return true;
  }
}

$('.view').val('card-1: ' + data);
$('.clear').on('click', function() {
  localStorage.clear();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <ol>
    <li>Enter text then click the <kbd>BLR</kbd> button to unfocus from the input thereby triggering the change event.</li>
    <li>Next, refresh this page and the text entered should be in the input again.</li>
    <li>In order to remove the text from localStorage, click the <kbd>CLR</kbd> button.</li>
  </ol>

  <input class='card-1' value=''>
  <input class='blur' type='button' value='BLR'>
  <input class='clear' type='button' value='CLR'>

  <output class='view'></output>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you just want to fade out the card (each represented by a section HTML tag) on click, so

```
$("section").click(function() {
  var card = $(this);  //get the card that is clicked
  var storage = card.attr("class");  //get the class name of this card
  card.fadeOut();  //hide it
  localStorage.setItem("local", storage);  //save the value
});
```

Next you would want the page to check whether there is any stored value so that you can hide the card.

```
$(function() {  //short hand for $(document).ready()
  var value = localStorage.getItem("local");  //get the value from local storage with the same key, which is "local"
  if (value) {  //if there is a value stored previously
    $("section." + value).fadeOut();  //get back the same card and hide it
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
What do I do if I have a section instead of input? <section class="card-1"></section> then I cant use .val? with your code the function works but still the cards shows after the page is refreshed

Comment: As I have said I use a section for my card not an input. How do I access an element(class) value without using the .val option?
Can I acess it with only the (".card-1").css ?

Very thankfull for answers!

Comment: If you can show what is the difference in the cards then only I would be able to provide help for your case, because it seems like you are trying to hide cards without knowing what is the difference between the cards. A HTML snippet of two cards would be helpful

Comment: I have five different cards with different classes. When you click .card-1, I want that card to fadeOut and saved in localstorage when you click.card-2, I want that to be fadeOut and saved to localstorage .
the cards look like this

<section class = "card-1"> <p> content </ p> </ section>

<section class = "card-2"> <p> content </ p> </ section>

Comment: Updated my answer based on your card's HTML snippet